# Android 6: DataPicker изменяет свою внешность

Tags: java, android, datepicker

Использую `DatePickerDialog` и настраиваю границы для даты:

```
DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), R.style.time_filter_daypicker_style, this, year, month - 1, day);
    DatePicker datePicker = datePickerDialog.getDatePicker();
    if (limitsVariant == LimitsVariant.UPPER) {
        datePicker.setMaxDate(limit.getTime());
    } else {
        datePicker.setMinDate(limit.getTime());
        datePicker.setMaxDate(new Date().getTime());
    }
```

Все работает, но странно.

DatePicker иногда выглядит нормально вот так:

[image: правильный вариант]

А иногда вот так:

[image: неправильный вариант]

Не пойму в чем дело. Проблема возникает только в Android 6.0. `time_filter_daypicker_style` просто устанавливает цвет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
datePickerDialog.setTitle("");
```

или

```
datePickerDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

и задать тот или иной параметр до `datePickerDialog.show()`